# Omelette stuck to pot on low fire with extra virgin olive oil

Tags: eggs, omelette

I've tried to cook an egg with some oil underneath on low fire, trying to make an omelette, but the egg still got stuck and when I turned it over a plate it collapsed apart. It was just some egg and hard cheese bits. Anyone know what went wrong?

Maybe it's because the small pot was not nonstick. I thought it would turn out ok anyways.

Hello, this post has been marked as a duplicate. However, I think it is not, because it is about trying to cook an omelette with a pot rather than with a pen (which, seems like it's something people world not do, but one needs to ask oneself why, besides, one may run out of pans because they may all be scratched, have burnt stuck to them, or be dirty, and a novice user may ask themselves, whether it may be worthy, to use a pot, instead of a pan, or whether it may even be feasible).

Thanks.

Comment: If this is your first time making eggs on non-nonstick, then it is expected. I think we even have a question which says "I followed all advice and it still stuck, why" - basically, you need to train doing it right.

Comment: I always buy cheap teflon for my egg cooking. A little butter and it works every time. Stainless can be very unforgiving to delicate soft things like eggs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using a pan for an omelette not a pot, as it makes it easier to get a spatula under the omelette. Also, if you are not using a nonstick surface, use a little more oil (or preferably butter) and get the oil hot in the pan before putting in the eggs (medium high heat).

Comment: Why does the oil need to be hot before putting in the egg, how hot does it need to be, and isn't extra virgin olive oil healthier than butter?

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson oil being hot prevents sticking. I've seen a couple of explanations why and I'm not sure which is the actual reason, but it definitely does help. See the duplicate questions as to how hot it should be. Whether oil or butter is healthier is a question for your doctor or nutritionist, not this site.